# Which is the bigger ion, F- or O-?

Tags: physical-chemistry, atoms, quantum-chemistry, atomic-radius

Well, according to the proton-electron ratio $\ce{O-}$ should be bigger than $\ce{F-}$

What about the charge/electron density in $\ce{F}$? Will it not affect the size of the atom of $\ce{F-}$?

Comment: I think $\ce{O-}$ is the bigger guy. Since $\ce{F-}$ have a complete octet and also have more protons than $\ce{O-}$.

Comment: @Siddharth Yadav, What about the charge/electron density in O?

Answer (score 4):

definitely $\ce{O-}$

In $\ce{O-}$ 7 outer electrons are tied to nuclei with 6 positive charges (number 8 minus 2 electons of inner shell), while in $\ce{F-}$ 8 outer electrons are tied to nuclei with 7 charges. The difference, however, should be quite small.